# Vector calculus identities

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f$ be scalar potential for the vector field $\underline u  $ (i.e $\underline u   = -\underline \nabla   f$).
Prove that the vector field $$ \underline  r  \wedge \underline u $$ has magnetic potential and find it.

Now, I have the solution to the exercise (which I almost completly don't understand) and its states the following:

$$  \underline \nabla  \cdot (\underline r  \wedge \underline u)=\underbrace {(\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline r  )}_\underline 0\cdot \underline u  -\underline r  \cdot \underbrace {(\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline u )}_{\underline \nabla \wedge (-\underline \nabla f)=\underline 0}=0$$
and that is why there exit a magnetic potential.
Which means, there exist $\underline A  $ such that $\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline A =\underline r   \wedge \underline u  $.

Now:
$$\underline \nabla \wedge (f \underline r)=(\underline \nabla f)\wedge \underline r +\underbrace {f (\underline \nabla \wedge  \underline r)}_{\underline 0}=-\underline u \wedge \underline r =\underline r \wedge \underline u $$

So that $f\underline r$ is answer.

I don't understand why the following are true:

- ${(\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline r  )\cdot \underline u}=0$
- $\underline r  \cdot (\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline u ) =-\underline \nabla \wedge (-\underline \nabla f)=\underline 0$

and why

$f (\underline \nabla \wedge  \underline r)=\underline 0$

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) What is ${(\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline r  )}$? (it's $\underline 0$)

2) You've misread/miswritten something. $\underline \nabla  \wedge \underline u=\underline 
\nabla \wedge (- \underline \nabla f)=\underline 0$

3) Again, what's ${(\underline \nabla   \wedge \underline r  )}$?

Comment: Original post edited. But I don't understand why $(\underline \nabla \wedge \underline r)=\underline 0$

Comment: @UdiBehar I don't know what or how you've been taught, but this is a basic fact. How would you define $(\underline \nabla \wedge \underline u)$ for some vector $\underline u$?

Comment: I know how to define it (like here:[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage)). It just that why in this case of the exercise the result is 0.

Comment: @UdiBehar Well, use the definition. It follows immediately (if you understand everything involved).

Comment: Let me get some time on this... Maybe I can get it.